# Cannot scroll on the left an centered img with flex

Tags: css, image, scroll, flexbox, center

I've read a lot of articles describing how to center a img bigger than the div container. But I also need to scroll that image horizontally (specially for mobile devices) and I cannot explain myself the behaviour I get and how to fix it.

I use flex (through bootstrap classes):

```
<section id="container">
    <div class="for-mobile d-md-none d-flex overflow-auto justify-content-center">
        <img src="image_bigger_than_div"/>
    </div>
<section>
```

Additionnal css:

```
.for-mobile img { flex:none }
```

The image is well centered and I can scroll on the right side but I cannot scroll on the left side. If I change the flex direction to row reverse, the opposite behaviour occurs.
Why? How to fix this please?

Thx

NB:
If I don't "justify-content: center", the img is not centered and I can scroll the full image.

Answer (score 0):

The code is working fine to me I had to close the section tag just as shown in the code snippet.

I also added class `img-fluid` to the image to make it responsive but if you want to scroll just remove that class.

```
<section id="container">
    <div class="for-mobile d-md-none d-flex overflow-auto justify-content-center">
        <img class="img-fluid" src="assets/images/image.jpg" />
    </div>
</section>
```

And I was able to scroll right and left without any problem...

I also believe the CSS code you provided is not needed.

Comment: Thx for your answer.
I do not want the img to be responsive because I want to see only a portion of the image on mobile and scroll it if the user want to see more of the image.

How do you check it is working properly? I use chrome devtool to emulate mobile device. I have the same behavior with Firefox devtool.

The added css is needed for firefox.

Comment: I use Chrome, any way you can remove `img-fluid` class and you can scroll left and right up and bottom without any problem but I don't think that's a good practice

Comment: So weird...
I will check on parent tags if there is a reason why.
Thx anyway :-)

Comment: see a jsfiddle, I can reproduce my pb. on mobile screen, I cannot see the left of the image:
https://jsfiddle.net/Laurent001/mu9s8jkw/

The more you reduce the img horizontally, the less you can see the left of the image (no scroll possible)

Comment: Are you sure it is working for you because on the previous jsfiddle and this codepen, I cannot access to the img on the left.
https://codepen.io/Laurent001/pen/bGpgver